# Laravel .htaccess not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel

Laravel's default .htaccess file gives an error on Php Cloud server.

**Error:**

> Option MultiViews not allowed here

When I remove section below from .htaccess my home page work but other routes gives an 404 error.

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
     Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

**Original .htaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Which cloud server provider is it?

Comment: Server provider is phpcloud.com

Answer (score 0):

Based on these [Google results here](http://www.elefantcms.com/wiki/Installing-on-PHPCloud)  and [here](http://www.eschrade.com/page/url-rewriting-in-phpcloud/), I think you need to append/edit:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

so in total:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```